# WSO2 changed wsdl file

Tags: wsdl, wso2

My service picked from a wsdl file. But the service wso2 published is chenged. If I want wso2 published just as my wsdl file. How to set?
For example, My wsdl file is:

```
<wsdl:service name="CoshipServiceImplService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:CoshipServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" name="CoshipServiceImplPort">
    <soap:address location="http://X.X.X.X:7843/sysway-boss-service/cxf/CoshipService" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

And WSO2 published like :

```
<wsdl:portType name="CoshipServiceImplServicePortType"></wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="CoshipServiceImplServiceSoap11Binding" type="tns:CoshipServiceImplServicePortType">
</wsdl:binding><wsdl:binding name="CoshipServiceImplServiceSoap12Binding" type="tns:CoshipServiceImplServicePortType"></wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="CoshipServiceImplServiceHttpBinding" type="tns:CoshipServiceImplServicePortType"></wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="CoshipServiceImplService"></wsdl:service>

It changed my port form "CoshipServiceImplPort" to "CoshipServiceImplServicePortType".
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done via setting the service parameter 'useOriginalWsdl' as true in your service.

```
<parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
```

From WSO2 App Server/ESB/DSS you can done via from UI

- Go to Admin Console UI.
- Navigate to  Manage → Web Services → List → Service Dashboard.
- From "Quality of Service Configuration" option in service dashboard, select 'Parameters'  option and add the above 'useOriginalwsdl' service parameter.